# Search result page blank page

Tags: magento2, layout, search, default.xml

Does somebody know why the xml bellow causes **blank page** on **search** result page ?

Im using `luma` theme and have custom theme with `Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`.

All pages are shown correctly exept search result like `catalogsearch/result/?q=xxx`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">148</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">43</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <!--<referenceBlock name="header.panel" remove="true" />-->
    <move element="header.panel" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo"/>

    <referenceBlock name="header.panel.wrapper" remove="true"/>

    <move element="navigation.sections" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo"/>

    <!--<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" after="-" />
    <move element="search" destination="header-wrapper" after="-" />
    <move element="catalog.compare.link" destination="header.links" />  -->

    <move element="top.search" destination="header.panel" after="header.links" />
    <move element="search" destination="header.panel" after="header.links" />
    <move element="catalog.compare.link" destination="header.links" />  
    <move element="minicart" destination="header.panel" after="header.links" />

    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true"/>

    <referenceBlock name="header" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="copyright" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footerlinks">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footerlinks</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

As I see, this `xml` should not cause a blank page for search page, I doubt about another file ! Please try to add this to your theme:

`app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog-search/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="page-products"/>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" name="search.result" template="Magento_CatalogSearch::result.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" name="search_result_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml" cacheable="false">
                    <arguments>
                        <!-- If argument's position depends on image size changeable in VDE:
                        positions:list-secondary,grid-secondary,list-actions,grid-actions,list-primary,grid-primary
                    -->
                        <argument name="positioned" xsi:type="string">positions:list-secondary</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml" cacheable="false">
                        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager" cacheable="false"/>
                    </block>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                    </action>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="catalogsearch.product.addto" as="addto">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                               name="catalogsearch.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <action method="setListOrders"/>
                <action method="setListModes"/>
                <action method="setListCollection"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Don't** forget to clean your cache and deploying a static contents

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: Thanks! I have copied file in p/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog-search/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml and p/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Search/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml (and run shell comands) but page is still blank ...

Comment: If I remove file Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml search result page is shown (but my theme is not correct then of course)

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by copying original xml from Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml into my custom theme and remove  tag

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">148</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">43</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="footer">
        <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="Magento_Store::switch/stores.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
    <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
```

.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below line in top of your themes "result.phtml" file at path app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Project}/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/

```
$productList = $block->getProductListHtml();
```

So your file starting should look like below :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
$productList = $block->getProductListHtml();
?>
<?php if ($block->getResultCount()): ?>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Compare Theme and Vendor file **default.xml** what is the difference.

Or check the log files.